# Voting API + Fivestar Voting - Restricting votes to user and not to IP

Tags: rating

I want [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) rating to be restricted to the logged in user and NOT to the IP they are using.

I want two (or more) logged in users using the same IP being able to have their own votings. At the moment it is possible to influence each other votings.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior.

Votingapi will limit to IP address when a user is anonymous. If the user is logged in the voting will be restricted by the User ID not ip address.

What version of votingapi are you using? If you're having a problem where this isn't the behavior a bug report might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, unfortunately (AFAIK) this is a limitation of Voting API.

When faced with the same problem in the past I ended up resorting to hacking the module and adding that functionality. (it was a while ago though, maybe something changed?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That really amazes me. Is there an alternative module to the Voting API which does provide this functionality?

Comment: This is not the case, votingapi, only limits by ip address based on the settings and if the user is not logged in. If the user is logged in it limits by users ID.